# Multiple files in /tmp/python.cache_root

Tags: python, caching

Running Python on a Raspberry Pi, I found that my /tmp folder was becoming full over time. On investigation, I found that it was becoming full of files of the form /tmp/python.cache_root/<1>/<2>/, where <1> and <2> are oct digits. These files were created when I ran a scheduled (self-written) Python script.

Googling "Python Caching" and related terms only turned up results from frameworks or products like Maya or Django, which were no good to me. Apologies if I've missed an obvious result!

Is this a sign of sloppy coding (e.g. unclosed resources), or simply something that Python does as a by-product of running scripts? Is there an accepted way to deal with this? Running `rm -rf /tmp/*` "solves" the problem, as does rebooting the Pi, but obviously these aren't desirable solutions.

EDIT: It's been suggested that the `python-twitter` library might be to blame, as per [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/issues/detail?id=232)

Comment: What does your Python script do? Does it use any particular libraries? I'm not sure there's going to be an answer without knowing more about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using [the `python-twitter` project](http://python-twitter.googlecode.com); it creates a temporary directory with the name `python.cache_<username>`, with that exact structure (based on a md5 hash).

On Raspberry you are running your code as root usually, so that fits.

Another python library that uses the exact same structure is [python-lastfm](http://code.google.com/p/python-lastfm/); the code was obviously copied between projects. Both projects have sprouted a few forks, so the method may be more widespread still.

Comment: Wow, impressive - I am indeed using that project! I'd assumed that it would clean up after itself - clearly not!

If you have any suggestions of how to clear those up, I'd appreciate them - if not, you've narrowed down my searching, thank you!

Comment: @scubbo: indeed, and that's been reported as a bug already: https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/issues/detail?id=232&q=cache

Comment: Heh, I discovered that bug at the same time as you pointed it out :)

I assume, then, that I'm safe to delete those cache files once the API call in question is finished?

Comment: @scubbo: Judging by the source code, yes it is. It'll use a `os.path.exists()` call to see if there is a cached copy next time.

Comment: According to [this page](http://static.unto.net/python-twitter/0.6/doc/twitter.html#Api), there is an option to prevent caching: `SetCache(self, cache)
Override the default cache.  Set to None to prevent caching.`

Comment: Sorry I took so long to accept this as the answer - not sure how it slipped my mind.